# override function in cocos2dx

Tags: c++, svg, cocos2d-x

I am creating level based game.   There is difficult to override SVG file in different level.

Here is the coding,

HelloWorld.cpp

```
 const char* HelloWorld::SVGFileName()     //virtual function
 {
   return NULL;
 }

CCScene* HelloWorld::scene()
{
   CCScene *scene =  CCScene::create();
   HelloWorld *game = HelloWorld::create();
   GameHUD *hud = GameHUD::HUDWithGameNode(game);
   game->hud_ = hud;
   scene->addChild(game);
   scene->addChild(hud, 10);
   return scene;
 }
```

level1.h

```
 class CC_DLL level1: public HelloWorld
 {
 public:
   level1();
   ~level1();
    const char* SVGFileName();
    void addBodyNode(BodyNode* node,int zOrder);
    void initGraphics();
 };
```

level1.cpp

```
 const char* level1::SVGFileName()
 {
    CCLog("LevelSVG: level: override me");
    return ("test3.svg");
 }
```

SelectLevelScene.cpp

```
void SelectLevelScene::level0()
{
   CCDirector::sharedDirector()->replaceScene(level1::scene());
}
```

My problem is,

I am not able to override the function SVGFileName() in level1.cpp.   Is there any problem in my code?

Any idea to fix it?

Comment: What mean that you are not able to? The compiler throw errors or the functions aren't call?

Comment: @WezSieTato: The compiler throws is "CCAssert(pszRelativePath != NULL, "CCFileUtils: Invalid path");". The function didnot call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return a const char* created in the function's local scope. This means as soon as the function returns the returned pointer is garbage.

You should return std::string instead.

Comment: #LearnCocos2D: i got my issue.  I forget to set HUD layer in level. It works fine.                                                    level1* layer=level1::create();
GameHUD *hud = GameHUD::HUDWithGameNode(layer);
layer->hud_ = hud;

Comment: and also                                                   std::string level1::SVGFileName()
{
    CCLog("LevelSVG: level: override me");
    return "test3.svg";
}